# VSCode not recognizing all .clang-format options

Tags: visual-studio-code, clang-format

I'm the kind of person who would systematically go through every single option available to toggle, and this time it's with `clang-format` in VSCode. I found [this](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html), which I'm assuming lists every single thing available to cram into a `.clang-format` file for VSCode to use. Unfortunately, VSCode seems to not recognize a handful of them:

1. `BitFieldColonSpacing`
2. `BreakBeforeConceptDeclarations`
3. `EmptyLineBeforeAccessModifier`
4. `IndentAccessModifier`
5. `IndentRequires`
6. `SortIncludes`
7. `SpaceAroundPointerQualifiers`
8. `SpaceBeforeCaseColon`

Out of the handful of options that VSCode fails to load, only `SortIncludes` is recognized at all, but it only accepts a bool, not the options that the reference says are available. The rest of the options are outright not recognized:

```
YAML:xxx:xxx: error: unknown key 'xxx'
Error reading /path/to/.clang-format: Invalid argument
```

Could I be missing something, or does VSCode not support those options? I'm using the C/C++ extension by Microsoft, using VSCode on Linux.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Clearly they asked you to report at GitHub https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quickish answer: This is not a bug.  At least some of those options (IndentAccessModifiers) are still in the "Work In Progress" clang 13.  You would need to (download and) replace the underlying clang-format binary in order to use these new features.

For whatever reason, the clang-format page describing the various options defaults to showing you everything in version 13, but does not actually warn you that these are not official release versions.  Nor does it at least tell you what version a feature was introduced.  It's not until you do a little digging that you find out that the main documentation page is not what you want.  The most recent VSCode uses version 11.1.0, and you can find the matching options here: [ClangFormatStyleOptions version 11.1.0](https://releases.llvm.org/11.1.0/tools/clang/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html)

**FUTURE NOTE**: This answer mostly only applies today May 27, 2021.  This may not apply 6 years down the line and VS Code is now at version 22 of clang.  That said, you may find this useful if you come across this same type of issue in version discrepancy.

Comment: That explains why I can't use some listed features. Thanks for the tip. VSCode should be able to use the system one though right? For example, I have MSYS and MinGW with Clang 12. I checked VSCode's clang-format binary and yes it is version 11 as you said, but I'm not sure how I would check other than trusting that it will use my system's binary if available.

Comment: So on my system the binary vscode uses is an embedded one, it's path being `/root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-vscode.cpptools-1.3.1/bin/../LLVM/bin/clang-format`.  I found that in the error output of the formatting.  If the extension is little more than passing all work off to the executable, you could move/change the name of that version, and create a symbolic link pointing to your system's implementation.  As long as the extension doesn't have specific ties to the embedded version it brings along, you _should_ be fine in doing that.

Comment: I'm currently on Windows and I believe I have found the Windows equivalent of that folder and binary: `C:\Users\User\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.3.1\LLVM\bin\clang-format.exe`. It's a lot larger than the one that I got from MSYS2, which I think means the VSCode one has it statically linked while MSYS2 has it dynamically linked - not sure whether VSCode would barf on it. Regardless of what version VSCode ends up using, how would I verify that I am indeed using a certain version, short of trying out features that should only be available on the newer one?